# Using sse broadcast with jersey, anyway to send an event to a specific EventOutput?

Tags: java, jersey, server-sent-events

I have a Restful service where a user can get a new SSE broadcast. The code looks like this:

```
SseBroadcaster sseBroadcaster = new SseBroadcaster();

@GET
@Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
@Path("/getEvent")
public EventOutput getSseOutput(@Context HttpServletResponse response) {

EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
sseBroadcaster.add(eventOutput);

return eventOutput;
}
```

What I'd like to do is when a new EventOutput is added to the broadcaster, send a welcome message to that EventOutput. However, everyone already listening to the broadcaster will also receive the message. Does anybody know of a way to send an event to a specific EventOutput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `eventOutput.write(event);`, where `event` is an object of [`OutboundEvent`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.17/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/sse/OutboundEvent.html).

Making the `OutboundEvent` appears to require a rather tedious builder class. See [the example](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html#d0e11479) in the documentation. I believe this is the minimum code to send a welcome message:

```
final OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
eventBuilder.data(String.class, "Welcome!");
final OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.build();
eventOutput.write(event);
```